# timing source auto card 1 in Digium

Tags: asterisk

I'm using the 4 port + 2 port digium card. Today I'm getting an error message in dmesg.
I saw in google , its like "timing source" value error . then I have change the span second argument

```
span=<span num>,<timing source>,<line build out (LBO)>,<framing>,<coding>[,yellow]
```

as 0/1/2 but the same error I'm getting. What is the Problem. How to solve this?

> timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 1!
>
> timing source auto card 1!
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   TE2XXP: Timing source already set to 4
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   TE4XXP: Timing source already set to 0
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   TE2XXP: Timing source already set to 4
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   TE4XXP: Timing source already set to 0
>   timing source auto card 0!
>   TE2XXP: Timing source already set to 4
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   TE4XXP: Timing source already set to 0
>   timing source auto card 1!
>   TE4XXP: Timing source already set to 0

my **zaptal.conf** file configuration is

```
#cat /etc/zaptel.conf
# Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/zapconf on Sat Mar 16 14:17:41 2013 -- do not handt
# Zaptel Configuration File
#
# This file is parsed by the Zaptel Configurator, ztcfg
#
# Span 1: TE4/1/1 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 1" (MASTER) HDB3/ 
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16

# Span 2: TE4/1/2 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 2" HDB3/ 
span=2,2,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=32-46,48-62
dchan=47

# Span 3: TE4/1/3 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 3" HDB3/ 
span=3,3,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=63-77,79-93
dchan=78

# Span 4: TE4/1/4 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 4" HDB3/                             
span=4,4,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4                                                        
# termtype: te                                                                  
bchan=94-108,110-124                                                            
dchan=109                                                                       

# Span 5: TE2/0/1 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" HDB3/                             
span=5,5,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4                                                        
# termtype: te                                                                  
bchan=125-139,141-155                                                           
dchan=140                                                                       

# Span 6: TE2/0/2 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" HDB3/                             
span=6,6,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4                                                        
# termtype: te                                                                  
bchan=156-170,172-186                                                           
dchan=171                                                                       

# Global data                                                                   

loadzone        = us                                                            
defaultzone     = us                                                            
ivr:~#
```

**ztscan  Output:**

> [1] active=yes alarms=YEL/REC description=T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 1
>   name=TE4/1/1 manufacturer=Digium devicetype=Wildcard TE420 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 0 basechan=1 totchans=31 irq=122
>   type=digital-E1 syncsrc=1 lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3 framing_opts=CCS,CRC4 coding=HDB3 framing=CCS [2]
>   active=yes alarms=YEL/REC description=T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 2
>   name=TE4/1/2
>   manufacturer=Digium
>   devicetype=Wildcard TE420 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 0
>   basechan=32
>   totchans=31
>   irq=122
>   type=digital-E1
>   syncsrc=1
>   lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3
>   framing_opts=CCS,CRC4
>   coding=HDB3
>   framing=CCS
>   [3]
>   active=yes
>   alarms=YEL/REC
>   description=T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 3
>   name=TE4/1/3
>   manufacturer=Digium
>   devicetype=Wildcard TE420 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 0
>   basechan=63
>   totchans=31
>   irq=122
>   type=digital-E1
>   syncsrc=1
>   lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3
>   framing_opts=CCS,CRC4
>   coding=HDB3
>   framing=CCS
>   [4]
>   active=yes
>   alarms=YEL/REC
>   description=T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 4
>   name=TE4/1/4
>   manufacturer=Digium
>   devicetype=Wildcard TE420 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 0
>   basechan=94
>   totchans=31
>   irq=122
>   type=digital-E1
>   syncsrc=1
>   lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3
>   framing_opts=CCS,CRC4
>   coding=HDB3
>   framing=CCS
>   [5]
>   active=yes
>   alarms=YEL/REC
>   description=T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1
>   name=TE2/0/1
>   manufacturer=Digium
>   devicetype=Wildcard TE220 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 1
>   basechan=125
>   totchans=31
>   irq=114
>   type=digital-E1
>   syncsrc=0
>   lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3
>   framing_opts=CCS,CRC4
>   coding=HDB3
>   framing=CCS
>   [6]
>   active=yes
>   alarms=YEL/REC
>   description=T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2
>   name=TE2/0/2
>   manufacturer=Digium
>   devicetype=Wildcard TE220 (4th Gen)
>   location=Board ID Switch 1
>   basechan=156
>   totchans=31
>   irq=114
>   type=digital-E1
>   syncsrc=0
>   lbo=0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
>   coding_opts=HDB3
>   framing_opts=CCS,CRC4
>   coding=HDB3
>   framing=CCS

Answer (score 0):

Pri interface is hi-speed syncronic interface based on 8khz timer.

Timer frequency can be supplied by external clock on other side of pri or linux clock used.

Anyway you have specify ONE source for all cards, otherwise you will get message like you have. To select one pri as timing source put in config line 1,in all other put 0. You current 1,2,3,4 mean priority. More info can be found here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+PRI

Comment: I have commented 5 ports and enabled only span 1 and I have changed timing source value as 0. for that also I'm getting same error.

Comment: i think you missed somethign. if you commented all except 1 you can't got error about timing go to 4. Please recheck,note it can be named dahdi.conf in modern installs.

Comment: Is there any option to enable zaptal debug mode.